# Highcharts - prevent accessing of points out of extremes

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this highcharts graph

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
    }]
});


// the button action
$('#button').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), Date.UTC(2010, 0, 8));
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/axis-setextremes-datetime/

If you click 'set extremes' it works fine for an interval of a whole day.

Changing the point interval to 20 * 3600 * 1000 (20h) and clicking again 'set extremes' you can access the point 'Friday, Jan 1, 20:00' which is out of range because minExtreme is set to 2. Jan.

How can I prevent the accessing of points which are out of the extremes?

Even at
    http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare
you can navigate to the left and access the May 9, 2012.

Comment: It is related with known bug, reported to our developers [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3916) so please stay on track with this thread, until bug will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `minPadding` to 0, and `startOnTick` to false will stop that point from being displayed in the plot area.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/rw3a5hq5/

Oddly, however, the first point still displays a tool tip if you place your cursor in just the right spot - which appears to be a bug, to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the start point when you set the extremes:

```
chart.series[0].update({pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2)});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ru7czqf7/).